# Assign value to a column based on the length of a list in another column

Tags: python, list, dataframe, lambda

| Col1 | Col2 | ListOfQs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | Third | ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'] |
| Second | Fourth | ['row', 'col'] |

I would like to create a new column in a DataFrame that contains the value in Col2 if the length of the list in df['ListOfQs'] > 2 and the value in Col1 if it's not.

I can get the length of the list with:

```
df['lenList'] = df['ListOfQs'].str.len()
```

but the type of df['lenList'] is a Series and it won't let me treat it like a number.

I tried :

```
df['lenList'] = pd.to_numeric(df['lenList'])
```

but `type(df['lenList'])` is still a Series.

If I get it to be numeric I can use it in a for loop. I'm thinking someone may know how to do this in one step using a lambda.  I will take any help I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where`:

```py
df["new_col"] = np.where(df["ListOfQs"].str.len() > 2, df["Col2"], df["Col1"])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     Col1    Col2         ListOfQs new_col
0   First   Third  [abc, def, ghi]   Third
1  Second  Fourth       [row, col]  Second
```

---

If you need to convert `ListOfQs` to `list`, you can apply `ast.literal_eval` first:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

df["ListOfQs"] = df["ListOfQs"].apply(literal_eval)
```